# Navigate through webdirectory in Browser

Tags: php, file, directory-listing

I'm currently trying the following:

I want to navigate through my webdirectory in the browser. So lets say I have a folder here: `/var/www` and I now want to be able, to navigate trough the folder structure on a site I make myself. So having clickable folders, and in that folders again folders, files etc., which should be all be downloadable. 
I already thought about the [RecursiveDirectoryIterator](http://php.net/manual/de/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php), but as this one only shows all file names at once, it's not what I need (as I want only the folders in the directory I'm currently in, and then if I click on a directory, being in there again etc (just like I would write (on the server): `cd test` `ls` `cd folder_in_test` `ls`, and so on, with the possibility to go back on the higher-level folder of course. Just the same behaviour as e.g. [here on dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/) or on [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com) and so on, I hope you know what I mean.

As I said I tried something like that:

```
<?php

$path = realpath('/etc');

$objects = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
foreach($objects as $name => $object){
    echo "$name\n";
}

?>
```

But it's just listing all files recursively from the complete `var/www`-folder, and this is not what I want.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    $dir = '/path/to/my/directory';
    $cdir = scandir($dir);
    $output="";
    foreach ($cdir as $key => $value)
    {
       if (is_dir($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value))
       {
               $output.="<div class='dir-div'  data-key='".$dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value."'>$value</div>";

        }
        else
        {
           $output.="<div class='file-div'>$value</div>";
        }

    }

?>
<div class="media-manager">
        <?php echo $output;?>
</div>

<script>
 $(".dir-div").on("click",function(){
     $.ajax({
         url:'somephp.php',
         method:'POST',
         data:{data:$(this).attr("data-key")}
         success:function(data){
            $(".media-manager").html(data);
         }
     }) 
 })
</script>
```

IN somephp.php

```
<?php
    $dir =$_POST['data'];
    $cdir = scandir($dir);
    $output="";
    foreach ($cdir as $key => $value)
    {
       if (is_dir($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value))
       {
             $output.="<div class='dir-div'  data-key='".$dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value."'>$value</div>";

        }
        else
        {
           $output.="<div class='file-div'>$value</div>";
        }

    }
echo  $output
?>
```

Comment: This works (except a comma you forgot), only added the nearly same code in your "somephp.php" file, so i can go recursively in the folders, not only one folder, and then theres no clickable folder any more. I just have one problem now: I can visit the complete file system now, so I can also go out of `var/www`, so for example navigate to `/etc`, do you know how to avoid that?

Comment: do you have any idea?

Comment: you can keep if condition 

if(substr($_POST['data'], 0, strlen("yourwebroot")) ==="yourwebroot")
{

         $dir =$_POST['data'];

}
else
 $dir ="path/to/webroot";

Comment: yeah, I thought about something like that as well, but then there is one problem: if somebody knows how to deal with html then it's no problem to go to another directory anyway because they can just press f12 in chrome for developer tools and then they simply change the content of data-key to the folder they want and they're in.... What to do know?

Comment: if they change data-key also not a problem, for that if condition will work like this,

for example, your document root is "xyz", now you want allow only xyz/images folder.

datakey always like this : images/folder1,images/folder2,images/file.jpg...
if condition will check directory is starting with images or not , if yes then it will go to sub directory(images/folder1/folder5), other wise it will show only images folder. i hope it will helpful..

Comment: The problem is the following: on your solution the data-key will always start with xyz as a url in data key could look like "xyz/images/../images/../images and so on, that's how a url looks like after navigating around a bit... You know what I mean?

Comment: No, change that to either xyz/images/subfolders or xyz/images only in else condition always data-key is xyz/images

Comment: Yeah, I got that that, but the problem is that data-keys like xyz/images/../../../.. are also working, and then is not caught by the if condition, as xyz/images is contained in it...

Comment: you know what I mean?

Comment: using str_replace("../","",$_POST['data']); then use if conditions

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109397/discussion-between-user5638730-and-purushotham).

Comment: This doesn't work as well...
Actually even clicking on my folder with "..", makes the user able to go further back

Comment: got it, had to use `realpath` and then it was easy going

Answer (score 0):

use scandir() php in built function. it will return particular files and dirname in that locatoin

```
 $dir = '/path/to/my/directory';
    $cdir = scandir($dir);
    foreach ($cdir as $key => $value)
    {
       if (is_dir($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value))
       {
         //your code here 

       }
    }

//This is one more example to get files recursively.

    function dirToArray($dir) {

       $result = array();

       $cdir = scandir($dir);
       foreach ($cdir as $key => $value)
       {
          if (!in_array($value,array(".","..")))
          {
             if (is_dir($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value))
             {
                $result[$value] = dirToArray($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value);
             }
             else
             {
                $result[] = $value;
             }
          }
       }

       return $result;
    }
```

Comment: but I see it right, that this only lists the files once, and when clicking on a folder, what hapens then? Or am I wrong?

Comment: use ajax call and get sub folder list, display the result, if folder add some class, by using jquery click event raise ajax call